# VB.net Check if there is are .xml file in certain folder (in loop) and process them individually

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a folder where a software generates random XML data file and couple of scanned images(which are linked in the .xml). I need to sort these images depending on data in .xml. The only problem is that the .xml file has random name. I just cant figure out a way to check if there are any xml files in that particular folder without a filename. And I would need a code that runs in loop until I press the stop button.

I have tried to make a start button "`Button3`" which on click triggers the check mechanism, but this would require user input after each cycle. So I want a loop to cycle and do this until I press the end button "`Button4`". `File.Exists()` function doesn't seem to work with wildcard (*.xml) names.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   Button3.Click
    If (TextBox1.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox("Please select xml folder")
    ElseIf (TextBox2.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox("Please select target folder")
    Else
        RichTextBox1.Text = "Process started..."
        Dim SourcePath = TextBox1.Text
        If System.IO.File.Exists(SourcePath+"/*.xml") Then
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Found one xml data, processing it now.. ")
            RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
            RichTextBox1.ReadOnly = True
        Else
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "No xml data found, looping ... ")
            RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
            RichTextBox1.ReadOnly = True
        End If


    End If



End Sub
```

While the code works when I replace *.xml with test.xml and trigger the check by pressing start button, I can't get a stable loop running with goto and since the filename is not constant, it is not feasible anyway.

P.S: `TextBox1` & `TextBox2` are OpenFileDialogs with each source and destination folder names. `RichTextBox1` is an embedded log.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) to get the files

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\temp"); //use your path

foreach(var file in di.GetFiles("*.xml"))
{
    //do your work.
}
```

Use a [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2) to watch for files and fire an event when changed

Answer (score 0):

> I just cant figure out a way to check if there are any xml files in that particular folder without a filename.

You can enumerate the files of the folder by using [`System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles) or [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles), using `"*.xml"` as the `searchPattern`, and then loop through the returned `IEnumerable<string>`/`FileInfo[]` processing the XML files as needed.

> And I would need a code that runs in loop until I press the stop button.

I would suggest making the Start button create a worker thread/task, and then make the Stop button signal that thread/task to stop.  Have the worker enumerate the folder looking for pre-existing XML files, and then monitor the folder for changes, such as with [`System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher) or [`ReadDirectoryChangesW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw), to discover new XML files being created/written.  Process the XML files as needed, and notify the UI thread of any status information as needed.

Don't run such a loop directly in the UI thread at all.  The UI thread should service the needs of the UI only, not of lengthy operations.